# Issue with IN() on a column with reserved word 'group'

Tags: mysql

```
select 
  id, fname, 'group', lname 
from 
  customers 
where 
  'group' in ('ADMIN' , 'SYSADMIN' , 'SALES');
```

If I replace the string 'group' preceding the *in* keyword with id, fname or lname and supply values which are in that column all is well... But I can't get co-operation from the above statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
`group`
```

Note on backtick, not quote char